# Cannot use `deflateInit` to compress the modified data

Tags: c++, http, zlib, winsock-lsp

I'm developing an LSP that monitors HTTP traffic and modifies the source HTML code of every webpage. To modify HTTP response that are chunked, I used `zlib` and `inflate` and successfully decompressed the data using the following main line of code:

```
r = inflateInit2(&z, 16 + MAX_WBITS);
...
r = inflate(&z, 0);
```

Now, after modification, I want to re-compress the data using the exact same method, so I'm using the following line of code but it returns -2.

```
r = deflateInit(&o, 16 + MAX_WBITS);
```

If I change `16+MAX_WBITS` it returns `SUCCESS` but it's not the same method and returns an invalid response after `deflate`.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `deflateInit2()`.  The fourth argument would be the `16 + MAX_WBITS`.  Please read the documentation in [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced)

Comment: You are right, now it's fixed but after `deflate`, `total_in=0x00000669` while `total_out=0x0000000a`! Why is that?!

Comment: You need to post a new question with the details.